# How to support right to left in oriantion changed?

Tags: android, orientation, right-to-left

I set `android:supportsRtl="true"` in manifest, and it work great. but by change orientation UI change to LTR. how solve It!

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.a.m"
android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.M">

    <activity
        android:name=".LargeImageActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.M2">
```

Comment: Did you put  android:supportsRtl="true" inside the <application> tag of your manifest?

Comment: yes! I  put android:supportsRtl="true" inside the <application> tag of my manifest!

Comment: post your manifest file